# Read multipile JSON objects from single file with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using `Jackson 2.6.5`.
I'm trying to read the following JSON:

```
{
    "metadata1":"value",
    "metadata2":"value"
}
{   
    "field1":"value",
    "field2":"value",
    ....
}
```

With the following code:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

But `jsonObj` contains only the "first" part of my JSON (the metadata), How can I read the "second" part of my JSON? (the part with the fields)?

**EDIT**

I know that my JSON doesn't contain "," so how can I parse it without "," between the jsons?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the JSON you added is missing a `,` sign between the two objects.

If you get such an `non-json` as input string, you might want to consider to:

1. First manipulate the input string by adding it the missing `,`  . E.g. find the location of `}{` and replace it with `},{`
2. And only then to insert it to the `jackson`

Comment: Yeah, I got the JSON without ","

Answer (score 0):

1. Your json is invalid, so you can't parse invalid json scheme by json parsing tools out of the box,
2. Instead you could read file by yourself into 2 strings - one valid json per string and then parse it with any json parser.